# Can't access variables of JSON response from REST-API in Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, object

I have a problem getting access to the variables in a JSON-File. I get the file as a response from a REST-API. Here you can see the JSON-File:

```
{
"_embedded": {
    "events": [
        {
            "name": "Josh.",
            "type": "event",
            "id": "Z698xZC2Z17CebP",
            "test": false,
            "url": "https://www.ticketmaster.de/event/josh-tickets/382625?language=en-us",
            "locale": "en-us"
```

I want to access the value (Josh) of the "name" variable in Javascript in line number 5 and store it into a new variable to use it later.

This ist how I try to do it:

```
var = data._embedded.events[0].name
```

But I can't get access to the value attached to "name".

I have read the answers to similar questions here, but there was no solution for me.

I have only read, that it does not work because of the wrong JSON-structure. In other threads, they say there has to be a "{" instead of a "[" in line 3. But I don't know how to change it in javascript directly. I tried it with the JSON.stringify()-method but it didn't work out.

Can somebody help me, please? Is there any way to get access?

I hope you can understand my problem.

Thank you very much!

Comment: [It depends on how you're accessing the JSON.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call) (But also `var = data._embedded.events[0].name` will give you a error).

Comment: Hello Andy, sorry I am a Beginner and I do not understand your hint/ Link. Which way for accessing the JSON would you prefer? And why will var = data._embedded.events[0].name give me a error?

Comment: Hey, no problem. We all start at the beginning. So start debugging. Open your devtools (F12), go to the console tab and type in `var = 'something'`. You'll see the error. It's because you're not assigning data to a variable. You may have meant something like `var name = data._embedded.events[0].name`.

Comment: The other thing is a little more tricky to diagnose. Can you add the code that you're using to get the JSON to your question as a [mcve]?

Comment: @LDP97 you json is invalid , can you post the real one pls?

Comment: @LDP97 is it the actual result from the Rest-API, if so, you may contact the REST-API creator for support.

Comment: you can try use online evaluator https://jsonpath.com/ , from your JSON structure use this JSONPath Syntax `$._embedded.events[0].name`

Comment: Thank you guys for all your help, even if I didn't post the whole JSON-File. I got it and I could fix the problem. With jsonpath.com and the JSON path syntax it worked! Thank you all very much!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your `json` structure has some errors. The `json` structure similar to the following is legal. Of course, it is no problem to use a legal structure to exec `data._embedded.events[0].name`.

```js
const data = {
  "_embedded": {
      "events": [
          {
              "name": "Josh.",
              "type": "event",
              "id": "Z698xZC2Z17CebP",
              "test": false,
              "url": "https://www.ticketmaster.de/event/josh-tickets/382625?language=en-us",
              "locale": "en-us"
          },
          {
              "name": "Josh.",
              "type": "event",
              "id": "Z698xZC2Z17CebP",
              "test": false,
              "url": "https://www.ticketmaster.de/event/josh-tickets/382625?language=en-us",
              "locale": "en-us"
          },
          //...
      ]
   }
}

console.log(data._embedded.events[0].name)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I had a problem with the structure and the JSON-Path-Syntax. Now it works!